# Colfdfusion loop status update Ajax

Tags: ajax, loops, coldfusion

I have a loop in Coldfusion which will run for a long time; about 2-4 minutes.

I would like to show a status update every time the loop has ran.

The loop:

```
<cfloop index="i" from=1 to=70>
    <cfset allHtmlFiles=getThirdXml.XmlRoot.XmlChildren[i].XmlChildren[1].XmlText>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(seekurl, allHtmlFiles)>
</cfloop>
```

The loop which takes care of showing data:

```
<cfloop index="loopcount" from=1 to=92>

    <cfset checkThisUrl = #seekurl[loopcount]#>
    <cfset completeUrl ="http://myurl.com/?ids=#checkThisUrl#">
    <cfhttp result="get" method="get" url="#completeUrl#">      
    <cfset nieuw =deserializeJSON( get.filecontent )>

        <cfoutput>
           <tr>
                <cfif nieuw[checkThisUrl].id IS NOT 0>
                    <td>#nieuw[checkThisUrl].id#</td>   
                </cfif>

                <cfif isDefined("nieuw[checkThisUrl].shares")>
                    <td style="text-align: right">#nieuw[checkThisUrl].shares#</td> 
                </cfif>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

How can I accomplish the Ajax update on every run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would so this is write the progress so far with a unique ID (like a UUID) to the database. Then you can use AJAX to poll through a *different* script to get the progress of the script.

The database table might look like this:

```
InsertedOn        | Data           | UUID
2011-02-12 13:01  | MyProcessData1 | MyUUID1
2011-02-12 13:02  | MyProcessData2 | MyUUID1
2011-02-12 13:03  | MyProcessData3 | MyUUID1
2011-02-12 13:10  | MyProcessData1 | MyUUID2
2011-02-12 13:11  | MyProcessData2 | MyUUID2
2011-02-12 13:12  | MyProcessData3 | MyUUID2
```

For example:

1. Kick off the process described above with an AJAX request. The request will start the code above as a thread (so it returns immediately) and return a UUID value representing the request
2. The process described above will write the progress to a database table with the UUID for each entry
3. Poll *using a different script* using AJAX every few seconds using the UUID value to find the progress so far

Perhaps there are other ways however!

Hope it helps. 
Ciaran

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a much better solution. Thanks!